# Antoniou gyrator with op-amps, simple explaination?

Tags: gyrator

I need to demonstrate that this circuit behaves like a gyrator:

[image: circuit][circuit](https://s15.postimg.org/cf1uhmoh7/Immagine.png)

Now, I made this new version of the image:

[image: edit][edit](https://s3.postimg.org/p0eogou6b/deee.png)

If I apply KVL to the blue surface I find out that the voltage on the top left resistor and on the bottom right one are the same and equal 1/2*V1 with reversed polarity, when I apply the same rule to the light blue surface on the right I find out that the voltage on the resistor equals V2 with reversed polarity, applying it to the red surface suggests me that the middle resistor has a voltage of 1/2*V1. In the end applying KVL to the perimeter of the circuit makes me believe that V1=2*V2. But how do I close my reasoning to demonstrate that this behaves like a gyrator?

Comment: I agree with the red and green loops. When the opamp have proper feedback their Vin (V+ - V-) is zero. I do **not** agree with the blue loop as it goes through the opamp, in via + input and out via output, I mean how can you determine the voltage across the opamp ?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie thank you for your answer, I just realized I was quite dumb! Now I was thinking...The current on the right resistor must be V2/R, same for the middle one, but how do I determine the current on the top left one?

Comment: Let's name the resistors from left to right R1 to R4 (this should have been in de schematic really). If you mean V(R3) = V2/R (green loop) then I would agree. The red loop with the opamp's input forces V(R1) = V(R2) (mind the + and - !!). Where does the current through R2 flow as well R.. ?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie so should I assume that i1 = V2/R?

Comment: Never assume, **prove** it. The other side: I2 = V2/R is easier to see. Then work your way back to I1. That is quite easy with the hints I already gave,

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie:being the current on R2 = V2/R and the current on R1 =V(R1)/R it must be that (for the red loop) V(R1)=V(R2) and therefore I(R1) = I(R2) (they share the same resistance and the same voltage so they need to have the same current). Right?

Answer (score 2):

You have posted an incorrect schematic. 
Here is a corrected one:
[image: Hand drawn schematic of gyrator]

Based on this resource:

https://sites.google.com/site/roelarits/home/gyrator

Notice in your schematic no current can flow through the bottom right resistor since it is connected to an op-amp input. That resistor is useless.

Comment: yeah I noticed that, in fact I never had to use the information about R4. That makes it a 0Ohm resistor and so V1=V2.

Answer (score 0):

Rusty_old_jfet is mistaken.  The circuit is correct.  It is a 2-port network and of itself is merely an implementation of a mathematical relationship.

As it is invariably presented in a synthesized inductor form with the capacitor shown, it is mistakenly assumed that the gyrator IS the synthesised inductor.

By connecting a capacitor to the output of a gyrator, the gyrator's input appears as an inductor. Rs serves a purpose when the network is placed in context and is therefore correct.